# Python - Weird invalid syntax error

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm trying to run a simple RPC server with a client that performs a few basic operations.  Everything seems to have been written correctly but trying to run the client produces an invalid syntax error that looks something like:

```
$ python rpcClient.py
  File "rpcClient.py", line 9


^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is the rpcClient.py file:

```
import xmlrpclib

proxy = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://localhost:7999/")
print "3 is even: %s" % str(proxy.is_even(3))
print "100 is even: %s" % str(proxy.is_even(100))
proxy.printString("Testing")
proxy.doubleList([1, 2, 4, 8])
print "Sum of all numbers from 1 to 5: %s" % str(proxy.sumList([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

I'm pretty sure the server file isn't the issue, but just in case it is, this is rpcServer.py:

```
import xmlrpclib
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer

def is_even(n):
    return n%2 == 0

def printString(s):
    print s
    return

def doubleList(l):
    for i in range(l):
        l[i] = l[i]*2
        print l[i]
    return

def sumList(l):
    s = sum(l)
    return s

server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 7999))
print "Listening on port 7999..."
server.register_function(is_even, "is_even")
server.register_function(printString, "printString")
server.register_function(doubleList, "doubleList")
server.register_function(sumList, "sumList")
server.serve_forever()
```

Any idea of what the issue is?  I've tried running the client repeatedly and I get the same error I mentioned above every time.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a closing parenthesis on the last line:

```
print "Sum of all numbers from 1 to 5: %s" % str(proxy.sumList([1, 2, 3, 4])
#                                           ----^                      -----^
```

Python then arrives at the next line, empty, and is wondering where the missing closing parenthesis went.

Note that the `%s` placeholder *already* calls `str()` on your interpolated values, you don't need to call `str()` explicitly here. Instead, wrap the values in a tuple, so that'll only ever be interpreted as one value to interpolate even if a tuple was returned from `proxy.is_even()`:

```
print "3 is even: %s" % (proxy.is_even(3),)
print "100 is even: %s" % (proxy.is_even(100),)
# ..
print "Sum of all numbers from 1 to 5: %s" % (proxy.sumList([1, 2, 3, 4]),)
```

Personally, I prefer the newer [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
print "3 is even: {}".format(proxy.is_even(3))
print "100 is even: {}".format(proxy.is_even(100))
# ..
print "Sum of all numbers from 1 to 5: {}".format(proxy.sumList([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Comment: +1 For mentioning that `format` is better.  There are too many old tutorials out there.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing parenthesis on the last line.  However, the call to `str` is unnecessary because the `%s` formatting option automatically converts its argument into a string.  So, all you need is this:

```
print "Sum of all numbers from 1 to 5: %s" % proxy.sumList([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: Thanks.  If it's Java, I'm incredibly meticulous, but since I'm still fairly new to Python, I'm prone to errors.